# Need help understanding the difference between a script format and query

Tags: database

This is a very newbie question I fear... I was wondering if there are folks on here that can tell me what the difference is between SQL scripts and SQL queries (I've been inadvertently using these terms interchangeably for too long).

I have plenty of experience executing queries (SQL server, oracle, postgres), but I started working with a group that requires I submit scripts with said SQL queries through their department for review and explicitly told me not to send them queries, but the scripts.  Can someone explain the difference for me?

If it matters, the SQL query I need to submit just joins fields from four tables together into one.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me out with this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context it sounds like they want to see any set of commands that will be changing (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.) data and are not concerned with any queries you're running to simply return or review data.

I suspect more people use these terms interchangeably than you think.

It's a very good idea to go back to this department unashamed and ask for clarification as different teams use different terms. I think you will find they're asking you to plan any data-changing action out in advance, put your commands in sequence in a file (like a .sql file if you work in Management studio, etc.) and forward that file to them for review.

Asking around was a great move. You cannot be too careful with these things!

Comment: reading in to this - it would be uncommon for the oversight guys to care about SELECT statements - unless they think they can help you optimize - it is almost certainly their concern that you are writing DDL or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements - which would go into a script with an extension of .SQL typically

Comment: Thanks for the advice. They're only select (read-only access already) so I think the primary concern is that they don't want me to set off any query that'll negatively impact performance.  I'll get back to them about the format specifically they're looking for and thanks for giving me some background on this!

Answer (score 5):

A query consists of a single command. A script is just a file with a bunch of queries.

See:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/user.32/e13370/sql_rep.htm

Answer (score 1):

A SQL script is nothing but when, you save a bunch of SQL statements (select, insert delete, update etc) in a file.

Comment: It doesn't look like the correct content for the answer. Try to fix it or it will be removed by the moderator. Please [edit] your answer to:

include [example] of your solution code, 

 include an explaination of how this works and why it is solution of the problem?
See [answer]